# How to define in JSON Schema an object property that holds an unknown JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

What would be a JSON Schema for an object of this model:

```json
{
    "mySchema": {
        // any valid JSON Schema
    }
}
```

I know you can define the property as an object, like this:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "mySchema": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

But can you define the value of `mySchema` as an unknown JSON Schema, but not a specific JSON Schema, and not only an object?

Here are the specs I was looking, https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html. It's not clear to me whether this is legit e.g.

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "mySchema": {
            "type": "object",
            "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON Schema, we have a concept of a "meta-schema". This is a schema that you can use to validate that a value is a schema. The meta-schema for any given version of JSON Schema can be referenced using the dialect URI you use in `$schema` to declare what version of JSON Schema your using.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "mySchema": {
      "$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
    }
  }
}
```

However, there is one limitation. If the schema uses `$id` to include embedded schemas and any of those embedded schemas use a different version of JSON Schema than the root schema, it might not work properly. For example, if you have draft-07 schema inside a 2020-12 schema, the meta-schema will validate the whole thing as a 2020-12 schema and not recognize the change in dialect.

```json
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "$id": "/embedded",
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        { "type": "string" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is a perfectly valid schema, but it wouldn't pass validation against the 2020-12 meta-schema. The array form of `items` is allowed in draft-07, but the meta-schema validates it as a 2020-12 schema where the array form of `items` was removed. It's possible to work around this limitation with a custom meta-schema, but that would get nasty and it's probably not worth the effort.

If you want to support not just any JSON Schema, but any version of JSON Schema, you can use `anyOf` and list all of the versions you support.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "mySchema": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema" },
        { "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't solve the problem I described. With this schema, the "mySchema" value will be accepted if the schema validates against 2020-12 or draft-07, but still can't use both for the same validation or know when to switch from one the other.

Answer (score 3):

You have the option to set `"mySchema": true` or `"mySchema": {}` in the JSON Schema. Both methods will always validate successfully regardless of the value of mySchema. Is this what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you @Clemens. I have used `true`/`{}` before, but haven't considered it in this setting.

You can say the value of `mySchema` is kind of external to the parent object and possibly does not even need any validation.

Comment: I was more looking for a yes/no answer, an interpretation of what the specs say. Is it possible to state "this is a schema", and if true, should implementations validate it as a schema, and not as just any json object?

Comment: But great, constructive idea. I'll consider accepting it.

Comment: I see. So this is different and I don't know if there is a recommended way to do so. Maybe someone from the core team like @gregsdennis can answer this?

Comment: to answer your question about `is this a schema and if true should it validate?`   Yes, `true` is a valid schema and yes, the validator will evaluate this schema and return `true` because it's a valid schema. JSON Schema validators don't know the difference between a JSON Schema or _just any JSON object_ other than a schema is defined with the `$schema` keyword, making it a JSON Schema.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Clemens' answer, it may be helpful to understand that in JSON Schema, keywords represent constraints.

With no constraints (an empty schema object `{}`), all JSON instances are valid.

As keywords are added (e.g. `type`), each one reduces the number of valid instances.  So if you want to constrain your instances to only JSON objects, you add `type: object`.

Additionally, some keywords only pertain to certain types.  For example, `properties` only pertains to objects.  But if you have a schema with only `properties` in it and no `type` keyword

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

the array

```json
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

is still valid because the type isn't constrained, and since it's not an object, `properties` doesn't apply and is ignored.